# Pegar valores de uma lista e coluna

Tags: python, matriz

Estou tendo problema com uma verificação, tenho uma determinada matriz com N linhas e N colunas, preciso percorre-la e saber em qual linha e em qual coluna possuí somente números impares.

Segue até aonde consegui fazer.

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [9, 6, 13]]
impares = []
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
        if matriz[i][j] % 2 != 0:
            impares.append(matriz[i][j])

print(impares)
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi de sua descrição do problema não é para verificar se um elemento da matriz é ímpar mas sim se *todos* os elementos da linha, ou coluna, são ímpares e, se forem, mostrar a(s) linha(s) e/ou coluna(s). Para seu exemplo apenas a primeira coluna.

Comment: isso mesmo mano, isso que tenho que mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma variável com um bool inicialmente True. Ao avaliar uma coluna, troque para False caso um número seja par. Assim, se a variável continuar True após avaliar a coluna inteira, então a coluna só possui ímpares. O mesmo para as linhas.
Ex:

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6], [9, 6, 13]]
colunasimpares = []
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    col_impar = True
    for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
        if matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0:
            col_impar = False
        if col_impar == True: # Avaliamos a coluna inteira e não achamos um par
            colunasimpares.append(j) # Matriz que armazena os índices das colunas ímpares
```

Algo semelhante para as linhas